# Can we do something to discourage ‘armchair history’ answers?

Tags: discussion, history-questions

Every once in a while, when someone asks a [history](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) question, there is a flurry of attempts to answer the question without referring to any supporting historical evidence. At best, such answers are purely speculative; at worst, they address an entirely different question. This is especially true of [design-choices](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-choices) questions, i.e. those asking about the rationale of some given design at the time it was created, where people often instead opine on whether the design makes sense to them personally, or try to guess the rationale based on anachronistic considerations.

Take for example:

- [How did the IEC decide to create kibibytes?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/) asks what rationale **the IEC** had to devise a new set of unit prefixes based on powers of 1024. Many answerers just wrote on whether they personally find separate set of prefixes sensible. At best disk manufacturers were blamed for the 1000/1024 confusion, without any sources given. The most authoritative answer was provided by Stephen Kitt, though ironically, [in a comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/#comment35457_11563).

  (Meanwhile, the quite similar question [Could we have avoided the whole UTF-16 fiasco?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14161/) has been closed as opinion-based, even though, ironically, the answers under that one are in fact much better grounded in actual history.)
- Under [Why was `!` chosen for negation?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/20085/), we have an answer attempt based on ‘emotional interpretation’, another (unsourced and, it seems, ahistorical) suggestion the symbol was borrowed from ‘propositional logic’, and another one that for example discounts `|` based on confusion with Unix pipes, ignoring the fact that Unix *and* pipes weren’t invented until much later.

(I may add more examples later.)

I guess, with computing being a quasi-naturalistic/-philosophical/-empirical domain, where a ‘why don’t you try it yourself’ attitude is common, there is a tendency to assume that the answer to every question may be derived from first principles or discovered by a simple experiment. History doesn’t work that way, though. Either your claims are based on a permanent record of what happened (which you may need to interpret to one degree or another, but you still need to have), or they are unfounded: it’s that simple.

(I can sometimes begrudgingly accept personal recollections of what happened: as faulty as human memory might be, it still beats trying to re-derive history from first principles.)

Personally, I just downvote such answers on the spot (and even vote to delete them when possible), but I feel this might be not enough, given that they also tend to receive a number of sympathy/[superficial upvotes](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/tornadoguard.png) as well, especially when the question ends up in Hot Network Questions.

What else can we do to have fewer answers of this kind?

Comment: I don't know but it's an excellent point well made.

Comment: Unless you *know* the correct answer, your downvotes are also just a matter of personal opinion.  The obvious way to discourage it is to ban all users with a rep of less than say 5,000 from answering any questions at all. Oh, and remove any rep points gained by voting for answers which are not "accepted" to stop people gaming the rep system :)

Comment: @alephzero, *Unless you know the correct answer, your downvotes are also just a matter of personal opinion* That's not at all true, there's not an equality of the two there. One doesn't have to know the exact answer to something to spot a wrong answer. Example [Q: When was the mouse invented? A: 1997 Reason: I was using one 10 years before - I know it's wrong but I don't know the right answer] and many millions more. Otherwise multiple choice questions would have no value.

Comment: Interesting that the ‘emotional interpretation’ answer for the 'Why was `!` chosen for negation?' has more upvotes than downvotes...

Comment: You could word the question so that it explicitly requests answers with sources. That's what I did when I [asked about a weird Fortran feature](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/19929/are-there-any-primary-sources-for-the-passing-constant-by-reference-behavior-i) recently.

Comment: Speaking as an armchair historian who occasionally comes up with actual references, I'm not sure why we want to discourage this. We're not professional historians. I enjoy the back-and-forth with people who have different views of the birth of whatever the hell it is that I get paid for doing every day.  Sometimes if it's my question, it's exasperating that all you heathens wander from the point, but I can live with that.  Even when it's clear that the only person who knows was the person who decided to use "!". The discussion, not the answer, is the point for me.

Comment: @another-dave We certainly shouldn't forbid conjecture or speculation entirely. I like DrSheldon's proposal, since it means that only questions with the `reputable-sources` tag will be strictly moderated, not all `history` questions in general. Discussion would remain perfectly fine in answers to non-`reputable-sources` questions and in comments.

Comment: One prerequisite for this would be for the SE site in question to generally accept that such questions would be left open and available for months on end until a primary source or participant were able to respond. Some SEs really don't like questions being open when an answer isn't immediately forthcoming.

Comment: Indeed I wouldn’t banish speculation completely, but it still should be considered a last resort, when it’s clear that all other routes have been exhausted, and clearly marked as such.

Comment: @texdr.aft - I'm not so sure about that; it grates my anti-authoritarian side, in that it allows the questioner (or indeed any other tagger) to control what is "allowed" in responses.  I prefer the current system where the questioner can indicate preferences, which wish we can then politely follow or impolitely ignore.

Comment: @another-dave, it's gotta be discouraged because the site's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. I know the answers to many/most of the questions I look at (adventurous, huh) - I get worn down by some of the memory-guess answers and I know what they're trying to say. Sometimes OPs say they want specific answers and still get a pile of guesses. Separate to that, there are some appallingly long, dull essay answers that it's painful scooping out bits of answer from chatty ramble. Rather see see more of the concise but freely-written, great quality, clear answers that this site's got in abundance.

Comment: Well, if we *want* this site to become as hostile as Stack Overflow....

Comment: @another-dave, jumping to some wild extremes, there. How do you connect guess answers OPs don't like with hostility...very odd. Please read my last line - where's the hostility? But you can't make it what it isn't and there's plenty of great discussion forums out there already if that's what you're looking for. You can have them too, not instead of, it's all free.

Comment: This site seems to have worked pretty well for the few years I've contributed here.  It has been loosely policed. Most of the interesting results have come to light by back-and-forth discussion between people who have different perspectives on historical events.  With respect to the 'hostility' - SO insists it is a Q+A site for "professional" programmers despite the self-evident truth that it's a site for questions from raw beginners, and this results in exessive zeal for closing questions on the flimsiest pretence.  I don't want RC to go the same way.

Comment: @another-dave, this question's made you imagine far worse than the specifics the question's about. Ironically, it means you're writing answer-comments that don't address the actual question - what the question's trying to stop :-) Ease down, no-one's trying to stop the site being pleasant. Just to see the back of that minority of rambling or long-winded that we'd try to get away from if these were actual face-to-face chats in a pub, back in the days when we were allowed out. Posts should be useful, they're not just to please the poster. Again, it's not a forum - it's a Q&A site. Always was.

Comment: I find, though, that it is often the case that a good faith answerer thinks he knows where something originated, only to find that someone else has a different angle.  Useful information emerges from the synthesis of the two.  Perhaps what I'm objecting to is the idea that we will know *a priori* what the answer is.

Comment: @TonyM ‘appallingly long, dull essay answers’ – I feel low-key called out by this. (Especially that I’d kind of agree; I’m somewhat dissatisfied how verbose my answers tend to turn out.)

Comment: @user3840170, I am glad I am not the only one triggered by that :)  Hopefully, there is still place for "long, dull essay answers", because that's how I tend to like them best.

Comment: @user3840170, hey, you're quoting me right out of context - I'd written "*some appallingly long, dull essay answers* ***that it's painful scooping out bits of answer from chatty ramble***". I also enjoy long answers that are suitable for the question and make a progress through their point - they're great and there's plenty here. It's those where I have to repeatedly sift through a lengthy text that jumps around and try and decode it to answer - they fail in their basic job: to answer the question clearly and readably. I'm not objecting to answer lengths there but to answer quality :-D

Answer (score 10):

*Sigh.*  Some of my own questions...

[Did the Apollo Guidance Computer really use 60% of the world's ICs in 1963?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/12158/10260)

> Please support your answer with references, rather than speculating.

[Origin of "arithmetic" and "logical" for signed and unsigned shifts](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/18066/10260)

> Please support answers with sources, rather than speculating.

[Why were relays prevalent in early 1940s computers when vacuum tubes were also available?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/19847/10260)

> "Because that was what was available" may possibly be an answer, but it needs to be supported by a reputable source, rather than speculation or argument.

...and yet most answers were pure speculation.

---

My suggestions:

1. Establish a new tag:

   > [reputable-sources](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reputable-sources)
   >
   > The person asking a question wants an answer supported by a reputable source.  All answers must include relevant quotes, citations, or links.  Answers based solely on opinion, argument, or speculation are subject to deletion.  This tag should never be the only tag on a question because this tag frames how a question should be answered, not the topic.  Please flag the moderators to add a warning banner to the question.

   (If you have a better name or description, put it in the comments below.)  Then the asker can choose if they want this.  Even better if we can make it one of those alternate-color tags.  The idea is similar to the  [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) tag in Worldbuilding.
2. Create a banner that moderators can add to the top of such questions:

   > This questions asks for **reputable sources**.  All answers should be backed up by relevant quotes, citations, or links.  Answers based solely on opinion, argument, or speculation are subject to deletion.
3. (Optional)  Allow an exception to the policy that speculative answers can be posted in a community wiki.  Not sure if this should be a general exception to the policy, or done on an individual question basis (e.g. different tags).
4. Aggressively delete answers that violate the above.  This is to be done by the usual flagging process and review queues.  Possibly add a custom reason for deletion.
5. Hold a vote here in meta approving such a policy.  This question itself doesn't count, as we are in a discussion phase.

---

It's worth noting that Monica Cellio (yes, *that Monica*) [came up with Worldbuilding's `hard-science` tag](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/should-science-based-henceforth-actually-be-science-based/1892#comment4185_1892).

Worldbuilding's policy on deleting answers that don't comply with the `hard-science` tag is [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3930/should-we-delete-answers-that-dont-meet-the-requirements-of-the-hard-science-tag).  Note that the top-rated meta answer is basically to leave it up to the community to police answers.  In practice, non-complying answers are given a warning and time to correct the problem.  Deletion is only done as a last resort, using the "low quality" reason.  There is very little work for the moderators (other than adding the question banner).  There is no "autopilot" that automatically deletes answers.

Read Monica's [meta answer](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5172/52704), and you will see that she also deleted answers for not providing supporting information.

Comment: Note there might be a severe misunderstanding on your side: Simply deleting answers they consider "wrong" is not (at all) the moderators' purpose. Incorrect answers have to be weeded out by the voting system and nothing else.

Comment: @tofro: I stated above that the deletion was to be done by the voting system.  There is no need to burden the moderators with that.

Comment: Incorrect answers are *never deleted*.  Only downvoted,

Comment: @tofro: That's merely a policy, and this is a proposal to change that policy for this site for a very specific situation.

Comment: It's a proposal to change one of the most basic policies that make SE tick.

Comment: @tofro: Yet Worldbuilding has such a policy.  (Whether or not it is followed through is up to the users.)

Comment: Now you have me baffled. How can worldbuilding have *incorrect answers*?

Comment: Can I add the 'reputable sources' tag to someone else's question?  Can that cause the autopilot to delete existing answers?  (Don't mind me, I'm a programmer; I'm *supposed* to think through the possible consequences of making changes).

Comment: @another-dave: No, you may not add the tag to someone else's question.  That's defacing a post, and should be rolled back and dealt with accordingly.  You may however encourage the asker to add it to the question.  There's no "autopilot" that automatically deletes answers.

Comment: @tofro: This meta answer has been edited to address your concerns.  Yes, Worldbuilding answers can and have been deleted for not complying with the question ("low quality").

Comment: This is bizarre. Worldbuilding is a bit of a special case in that it's an ideas repository more than a Q&A site, but no other site makes the user explicitly request the answers aren't pulled out of answerer's behind. Imagine if, on English.SE or ELU, you had to add a "reputable-sources" tag to a vocabulary question so that the answerers don't just make up words.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski: Wrong.  Just try posting a non-sourced answer to Skeptics, and see how fast it is deleted.  And English *does* require answers to single-word-requests to be supported by a definition or quote from somewhere else.  It's strange that you think requiring sources is unreasonable for a Q&A site, and that writing an answer out of your behind is okay.

Comment: @DrSheldon you seem to be violently agreeing with me. My point isn't that it's unreasonable to require sources, my point is that it's unreasonable to make the asker request sources when this is simply implied on any other site. Why would I ever want not to put that tag on my question? If the answer is "never", why do I need a tag?

Comment: @MaciejStachowski: It wasn't clear who you were addressing as "bizarre" in your first comment.  Perhaps we do agree.

Comment: @DrSheldon I do find the idea of requiring the reputable-sources tag somewhat bizarre. To me being able to source your answers with at least secondary sources should be the default, and anything else should be either opt-in, or closed as opinion-based. (Doubly so for "justification" questions, where I could come up with 20 potential reasons for each of them, none of them valid).

Comment: @MaciejStachowski - the comparison to "making up words" is extreme. I don't think we're talking here about raw invention but about informed speculation. The nature of RC is that personal recollection about events of 50 years ago often gets to the heart of the answer.

Comment: Isn't RC "reputation" an indication, admittedly imperfect, of whether an answerer is a "reputable" source?

Comment: @another-dave: No, reputation is strongly correlated to how early the answer was posted, not the reliability of the information in the answer.

Comment: @another-dave I don't think personal recollection on its own should stand as a source on here any more than it should on History or Politics. Or, to drag out the ELL/ELU comparison, being a native speaker should not mean anything you say about English is automatically right.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski  Many of those who contribute to RC seem to disagree. And we have personal knowledge of the history, being there and then.

Comment: @DrSheldon - then perhaps SE should get its "reputational" system in order, before it starts deciding what is and what is not "reputable" for others.

Comment: @another-dave For all we know, [you're a dog, and I'm a dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog). But even discounting malice, people misremember things, take gossip and urban legends as truth, or extrapolate their experiences to the entire industry.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski -- *extrapolate their experiences to the entire industry.*   And that's one of the points of permitting 'speculative' answers. We get a bunch of views of different parts of the elephant, and from that, an overview emerges and we can figure out what the elephant looks like.  No-one knows the whole picture, but collectively, we can come close.  SE likes to throw around the word "community". This is how it works. There are people here who have reliable views on topics, even though they aren't "reputable" by some arbitrary standard.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski, what you don't seem to appreciate is that what you think are citations in reliable sources are open to all the same criticisms that you are throwing around here. Even a peer reviewed academic paper can easily offer an unbalanced view or personally coloured judgements. Ultimately, the quality of responses is not decided by the quality of citations people choose to employ. Esp. when questions are forcing opinions that cannot possibly be justified by a reference, because, believe it or not, not everything is known, decided and available on the internet, or even in print.

Comment: @introspec: Even if a true answer is not available, that does not justify pretending that someone's guess is a true answer, nor should it preclude an asker from trying to get the true answer.

Comment: @introspec There's reliable sources, unreliable sources, anecdotes from anonymous people on SE, and speculation. And some questions are not answerable with a reference, but that's fine. If I ask "how were Windows logo colors chosen", I'd expect an account from a Microsoft engineer (or a contemporary article, etc.), not an answer from someone at SE purporting to have worked there or someone just speculating they went with primary colors. Other sites distinguish between original research and references just fine, why can't RC.SE?

Comment: @MaciejStachowski, other sites, e.g. Wikipedia, on some occasions threw out original content by top people. An account from a Microsoft engineer won't cut it at Wikipedia, because they don't accept personal accounts. At the same time, there are many engineers, incl. from Microsoft, who shared their personal accounts at this very website. What I am trying to show is that references do not magically appear out of thin air. Someone has to do an original research. And prohibiting original research in the articles is insanely misguided. Yes, not everyone can do it well. We have voting for that.

Comment: @DrSheldon, every piece of research starts as someone's guess. Who made you a judge of its quality? To Illustrate, I have had a look at your Qs and As. Your top question is about the difference between . and -> in C. You gave yourself a tick for the top answer, seemingly because you found a citation from K&R that explains why both operators are necessary. At the same time, you didn't accept a higher ranked and earlier answer by supercat, which states the same thing very succinctly and mentions the same original source.

Comment: This makes me think that you put unreasonable emphasis on a formal aspects of answers, such as the presence of formal links etc. Well, my point is that this is a flawed perspective and it does not apply in many situations. Say, someone contributes a new piece of code to their post. Or analyses someone else's code. This would not pass your abitrary requirements of not "expressing opinions out of one's ass". At the same time, if I go and write something in my blog (e.g. in my professional capacity), then I can add a citation to my answer to make it count more? This is not reasonable.

Comment: My real point is: in any field of human activity, there are differing opinions, however close the people were to the source of original informations. It is OK. Good answers on this website use all sorts of approaches to come up with answers that they believe are representitative. Some answers are not good. Some answers are too shallow or not grounded in enough facts. However, what makes them bad is not the fact that they are too personal or opinionated, or that they do not include enough citations. They are bad because they do not reflect the current understanding on the specific topic.

Comment: @introspec, I think you're arguing over the fine detail of the exact border. The guess-answers I objected to are obviously far over any line. Posters know when they've invented/'deduced' an answer, rather than seen evidence of their answer or are relating established fact. Go back to basics: this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. So venturing unsubstantiated opinions, no matter how much fun it is (which is most of the trouble), is the problem. Readers might pass off what they see here as fact, breeding disinformation. That's a common internet problem but let's not deliberately add to it.

Comment: @TonyM - do you have evidence (from a reliable source :-)) that most RC questions can be magically answered without "discussion"?  Because my experience here says otherwise.

Comment: @another-dave, you do love rewriting what I've said, then start laying into what I *didn't* say :-) Keeps happening. Find the bit where I say "most RC discussions" and I'll answer it. Oh look, I say minority. I have evidence of that and it's all on this page. You read like you'd made your mind up before you started typing anything here. Kills any useful discussion and progress.

Comment: You said "this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum",  My point is that, for RC, the former often (I would say generally) requires the latter. I've made that point before, but it seems to be ignored.

Comment: @another-dave, no. I directly answered that point on 27/28 Jun posts. But, like I keep saying, you're not referring to my points that I spent time writing. And RC doesn't require discussion anything like as often as you're saying. Sounds like you just want it to. As said before (I've said all this before), plenty more sites you can use *as well*. Anyway, if you're just going to throw out comments without listening, we'll get nowhere like we're doing now and I quickly get bored with that :-) Sit and read all the posts...then comment. Adios.

Comment: I find your response to be condescending.

Comment: @another-dave, not in the slightest.

Answer (score 2):

I think this type of questions is asking for it. They are just opinion-based questions in disguise. Of course, we can probably think of examples of questions of this kind where somehow (miraculously) a well-sourced answer has actually been given. However, frankly, if you really ask for explanation "How did the IEC decide to create kibibytes", you've got it coming, because even the explanation from IEC website linked to by Stephen Kitt is nothing more than some plausible hand waving.

So, overall, for specific situations where poster expects for some reason that precise answer must exist, DrSheldon's protocol of enforcing sourced answers may be helpful. However, I would be very wary of extending his suggested mode of moderation too widely. The whole idea that reliable information must be supported by "reliable sources" is a bane of Wikipedia and it would be wise to avoid implementing something similar here. Many specific questions on this site were answered by running a program, or looking into an open code, or by disassembling some old binary. None of these examples fit the narrow Wikipedia-like definition of "reliable source". The possibility of presenting your own research is what makes StackExchange really helpful.

Ultimately, the real problem that you are trying to solve is that voting disproportionally benefits quick answers, not well-researched answers. Well-researched answers given late are often treated as irrelevant, esp. for questions with many answers. So people are actively discouraged of doing any serious research if the question already has 5-10 answers, because they know their research won't be read anymore. If you can address this dynamic, many of your concerns will be addressed automatically.

Comment: My proposal leaves it up to the question asker.  If the tag is not added to a question, then speculative answers are allowed.  It seems to work well for Worldbuilding.  Also, I completely agree that fast answers are unfairly rewarded more than well-researched answers.  An answer that is well-written but a day late ends up below poorer-quality answers, and has a hard time rising to the top.

Comment: Totally agree that some of these "history" questions really provoke (sometimes, even more or lesss obvious, but still) speculative answers. More often than not, it's the question style that's bad, not the answer.

Comment: Three downvotes and not a single comment to express your actual opinion? This site used to be a lot more transparent.